# How to deserialize a JSON in Blazor?

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON from an API,

```
{
   "Cards":[
      {
         "ContentType":3,
         "Content":"robgra"
      },
      {
         "ContentType":4,
         "Content":"Rob Graham"
      },
      {
         "ContentType":1,
         "Content":"https://www.mineralblue.net/images/robgra.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

And i am trying to deserialize it in my .razor page. So far I have  deserialized it into a string using,

```cs
   using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
   APIreturn = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<string>(responseStream);
```

But i want to break it up into ConntentType and Content, i've been trying to save it as an IEnumerable object, but i keep getting an error saying the input does not contain any JSON tokens.

For example my code looks like,
`Deserialized = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<MyObject>>(responseStream);`
But i can't figure out how to format my public class object so that i can successfully deserialize it and access individual classes.

I've tried using `[JsonPropertyName("Cards"]` but it didn't work. How would i format my object so i can deserialize this JSON?

Comment: nothing related to blazor?

Comment: Post your JSON here: [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/), it will generate .Net classes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Let VS do the work. Copy your JSON to a class file and use Edit | Paste Special | Paste JSON as classes and  ....

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Card[] Cards { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
    public int ContentType { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I used this, and declared my object as private IEnumerable<Rootobject> response = Array.Empty<Rootobject>();, then used response = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAzync<IEnumerable<Rootobject>>(responseStream); but got the same error, am i using the wrong method?

Comment: `DeserializeAzync<Rootobject>(...)`